# Notepad ++ Export full "Find Results" window

Tags: notepad++, window

I have a large number of text files in multiple sub directories that I need to scan for a particular string and return the file names of any file that has this string inside. To do this, I have used the `Find in File` feature to give me an output which tells me all the files that match as well as the line number (exactly what I want)

However, when I `select all` and `copy`, only the matching strings are copied, not the file names and `Line x` part of the output.

Is there a way to export the full results (with file paths) of the `Find Results` window in Notepad++?

Comment: Hmm. I can't repro this https://i.imgur.com/agCm9lE.png

Comment: I fixed my own problem, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 8):

In npp 7.5.6 there is a difference if you, after selecting lines of the find result list, use "right click" / "Copy", or of you use "CTL-C".

"right click" / "Copy" copies the lines without line numbers.
"CTL-C" copies the lines with line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

What is selected when you click `Select all` is affected by where you click `Select all`. If you right click on a line found and select `copy` you will get only the lines found.

[image: Example]

If you click on the file name and select `copy` you get the full output.

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 2):

I had this basic issue too. I discovered that if you copy the hit report (CTRL+A and then drag and drop) into the editor screen, it'll preserve the pathname information. From there, you could either manually use the pathname, massage them to be links, or put them into some format that automatically renders pathnames as links.

Cheers!